# Monitor is not working with my VGA adapter on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hdmi, vga

I recently upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. I have a Samsung 21" monitor with both VGA and HDMI ports. I also have a Samsung 32 in TV which I want to use as a primary monitor. The PC is a dell optiplex-gx620 with 4g ram and a Pentium 4 3.6 GHz x2 processor. The graphics is Intel 945G. The VGA works fine with my 21in the monitor, however, since the Samsung 32" TV only has an HDMI port I bought a HDMI to VGA adapter but when I co next it to the TV it says no input or weak source. What can I do to correct this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a VGA to HDMI adapter once - it required separate power via USB - did you plug it into USB?  The other possibility is that your monitor doesn't support the resolution or refresh rate the Intel GMA 950 (graphics) is putting out to the (adapter > monitor).